# How to retry a serializable transaction with JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

When committing a `SERIALIZABLE` level transaction, we know it might fail with `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions. Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during write. Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.`

Can I somehow tell JDBC to simply go ahead and retry the transaction, or do I need to go back and manually execute the queries in a new transaction myself? If I can let JDBC handle this, are there any special cases I need to handle, such as a maximum number of retries, and/or a delay between retries?

Any insights will be welcome.

Comment: No, there's no automatic retry in JDBC. There might be something like that in some other frameworks, but not straigt JDBC. Retry manually and design your code so that it's easy to do.